# AudioGraph created files works in VLC but not elsewhere

Tags: audio, windows-runtime, wav, file-format

I've written a program that produces wav files using the WinRT AudioGraph API.

VLC plays the files fine, and displays the correct length.

But when trying to load the files in python

- `torchaudio`, `librosa`, `scipy.io` all say the file has no samples
- `wave` says "not a WAVE file"

I understand that AudioGraph probably uses a [newer wav metadata format designed for streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/extensible-wave-format-descriptors). Is there same easy work around? like using ffmpeg.

I think maybe the best thing to do is to load raw bytes into pytorch tensor and slice of the metadata.

Comment: This official sample here (scenario2 device capture) https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/AudioCreation records a .wav from an input. This .wav seems fine. Have you tried it? Otherwise please provide a reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out what's gone wrong tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AudioGraph` API has an [`AudioFileOutputNode.FinalizeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiofileoutputnode.finalizeasync?view=winrt-22621) method which solved this problem.

Previously I was just calling [`AudioGraph.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph.close?view=winrt-22621) a synchronous method and apparently this wasn't good enough.